# Python hardcoded context manager

Tags: python

I have to execute a code that looks more or less like this:

```
FPGA.send('enter read mode')
FPTA.send('read')
FPGA.send('exit read mode')
```

I would like to ensure that the `'exit read mode'` line is executed no matter whether there is a problem in the `'read'` line. The most elegant way of doing this in Python is with a context manager. However I don't want to write the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods for this `FPGA` object as this is just a particular case. I would like to somehow "hardcode" this context manager behaviour when I do this reading. I think that a `try` `except` block would do the job:

```
FPGA.send('enter read mode')
try:
    FPGA.send('read')
except Exception as e:
    rise e
finally:
    FPGA.send('exit read mode')
```

but I am wondering if there a more pythonic way of implementing this?

Comment: Why do you think that the try/except/finally is NOT pythonic?

Comment: The [with statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) says - `This allows common try…except…finally usage patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse.` So writing a context manager seems also Pythonic but you have rejected this as an option.

Comment: btw note that you don't need to do `except Exception as e: raise e` -- this is basically a no-op because uncaught exceptions will already raise.

Answer (score 2):

The `contextlib.contextmanager` decorator provides a nice shortcut for creating context manager objects in such a way that you don't need to implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def read_mode():
    FPGA.send('enter read mode')
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        FPGA.send('exit read mode')
```

Then you would use this context manager like this:

```
with read_mode():
    FPGA.send('read mode')
```

The `yield` in the `@contextmanager` function yields control to the block of code inside the context.  When the context exits (whether normally or via a raised exception), the `finally` block is executed.